# Manifest issues with maven

Tags: java, maven

I have created a core Java maven project that has a main class. The class runs fine in Intellij, but when I create a jar using `mvn clean install`, it fails to run with `ClassNotFoundException`. I understand that my maven dependencies are not added to the classpath, but how can I add them? I don't want to create a jar with dependencies unless absolutely required.

Here's the build tag of my `pom.xml`

UPDATE: As suggested by @devman, I have added maven-dependency-plugin. The pom below is the updated one. But still the `lib` directory is not getting created in the `target` directory after running `mvn clean install`. Somehow, I am also not seeing this plugin in Intellij but seeing some plugins that are not there in the pom. Below is my updated `build` tag of pom.xml.

```
<build>
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-jar-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.pkg.MyApp</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-dependency-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                        <excludeScope>provided</excludeScope>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Below is a screenshot of what I am seeing in Intellij under maven->plugins
[image: Intellij maven plugins screenshot]

Comment: 1. " I understand that my maven dependencies are not added to the classpath" ..please check! 2. "but how can I add them?" ..better question: what does/which effect has `<classpathPrefix/>`?;)

Comment: @xerx593 what does/which effect has `<classpathPrefix/>`? Where is the lib directory created by default and how can I run the jar to include it in classpath?

Answer (score 1):

You can build file jar, replace value in com.thanbv1510.MainApp with your main class

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>${java.version}</source>
        <target>${java.version}</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-jar-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
        <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            <mainClass>com.thanbv1510.MainApp</mainClass>
        </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-dependency-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
            <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
            <excludeScope>provided</excludeScope>
        </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: is ${project.build.directory} `target` by default? How can I give relative path to target directory here?

Comment: this is a relative path, it will be in your project, you can replace it with an absolute path

Comment: Found it. But running `mvn clean install` still did not create the lib directory

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, removing the `pluginManagement` tag solved the problem. If someone can explain why it was not working with this tag, I'll accept the answer.